# Consul all service checks failing with service with server ssl enabled true

Tags: java, spring, docker, ssl, consul

first of all I'm newby, sorry if I'm not totally correct with my question :).

I had problems when registering a microservice into consul. I had a microservice in spring, called gateway where I want to activate ssl.

Here is my application.properties:

```
spring.application.name=gateway-service
server.port=8080
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.instanceId=${spring.application.name}-${server.port}-${random.int[1,99]}
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.prefer-ip-address=true
spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.enabled=true
spring.cloud.consul.config.enabled=false
spring.cloud.consul.host=172.17.0.1
spring.cloud.consul.port=8500
spring.cloud.consul.discovery.scheme=https
server.ssl.enabled=true
server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore/XXXX.p12
server.ssl.key-store-password=XXXX
server.ssl.key-alias=XXXX
```

if I put server.ssl.enabled=false, when I go to the consul admin page everything is fine, but if I activate ssl, I see "Serf Health Status" tick in green but "Service 'gateway-service' check" in red in a wrong state. The curious thing is if I made some request with postman them are working ok and through https and the url and the url: https://XXXX:8080/actuator/health present the message status   "UP".

I had consul and gateway service mount in respective docker images and load with docker compose.

In my gateway I created the following filer:

@Configuration
public class ResourceServerSecurityConfig {

```
@Bean
public SecurityWebFilterChain configureResourceServer(ServerHttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    return httpSecurity
            .authorizeExchange((exchanges) -> exchanges
                    .pathMatchers("/actuator/health/**").permitAll()
                    .anyExchange().authenticated()
            )
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            .build();
}
```

}

apparently /actuator/health are permitted, any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

I establish a url for gateway, and spring.cloud.consul.discovery.scheme=https, I can enter to the url of actuator and apparently it's ok...

Comment: how are you setting up the certificate for your apps https connection? are they signed by a CA that consul trusts?

Comment: Hi Chris, I used the java keytool to generate a p12 certificate, with PKCS12 format but I have no modified consul configuration (no add certificate) I 'm not sure if it's necessary to create a certificate for this.Also in consul ui I receive the following message:

Get "https://172.31.0.4:8080/actuator/health": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: cannot validate certificate for 172.31.0.4 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs

where 172.31.0.4 is my service ip.

Comment: What is the CN of the certificate. Normally the CN will be the dns name but you can add alt names like local host or ip address. But the cert will still need to be trusted by the consul process/server

Comment: the last tests I have done, I erased the certificates an regenerated specifying the service ip (I fixed in docker-compose file) when I create the certificate, I verify that if I go to service/actuator/health it's ok, but in consul still marking error

Comment: But does the process / server running consul will need to be able to verify the chain of trust of the application certificate. So what CA is signing the cert and does consul trust that CA